# Selecting rows where array elements in Array Rails ActiveRecord/SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, postgresql

In Rails 4/Ruby 2.1, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
@user.submissions.where(:submission_codes_array => valid_submission_codes_array).count
```

Sort of similar to when you want to see if the `:id` if within an array of possible values (i.e. `.where(:id => valid_ids)`, except in this case checking if a particular attribute (which is a postgres array type) includes ANY values that are within the set of possible values, in which case it is then counted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't do it through ActiveRecord because you're using Postgres-only features (aka, I don't think mysql supports the functions you need).

What you want can be found here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-array.html

Specifically, you'll end up with something like `Model.where("submission_codes_array && ?", valid_submission_codes_array.to_s.gsub('"',"'"))`. The `&&` operator will check for overlap (aka, set intersection) between the two arrays, if I'm reading the docs right.

Note that, alas, ActiveRecord doesn't serialize the array into the form Postgres likes, so you gotta tweak it a bit.

Comment: Awesome, just got it to be functional. Originally was having some issues, as I was doing this: Model.where("submission_codes_array && ?", [1,5,2].to_s). But it appears as though the second array you pass in needs to have the proper Postgres array format. So something like this worked: `Model.where("submission_codes_array && ?", '{1,5,2}'")`.